# iOS Download code when app is running

Tags: ios, ios8, runtime, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I am aiming at downloading code (library / framework / bundle) when the app is running. This is like download specific modules based on user's ACL. 
I have gone through creating static library and framework which seems like we need them when code signing app. 
But I need the code to be downloaded when user is using the app and run that code. 
Pls provide some samples

Comment: Apple does not allow apps that download and execute code.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks. Any references for this from apple website?

Comment: Yes, it is in the [AppStore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). 2.8
Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected and 2.7
Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected