# Android app bundle (dynamic feature) for ios?

Tags: ios, dynamic, bundle

Is there someting like android app bundle for ios? Even for android this is beta feature. The concept of my app depends on this feature and now i'm thinking how to release my app with that feature for ios.
I have a lot of modules which the User can choose and install while runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is something kinda *similar*, but not the same and it does not provide the same functionality:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html

The On Demand Resource provides data, resources packs, but not executable code.

The real problem is that an Ios app should provide all the code in the submission phase. This means, for what I know, that it is not possible to distribute executable code which has not been submitted and reviewed (so dynamically downloaded and loaded modules...). However:

> Files generated by scripting languages can be on-demand resources.

So there is probably an open door to scripting languages, as far as the app has been approved.
Please look also at this answer:

[Adding a Framework on iOS in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042290/adding-a-framework-on-ios-in-runtime)

Comment: "The real problem is that an Ios app should provide all the code in the submission phase" = perceived problem. Android overcomes this with the new bundle (.aar) format where all the dynamic feature modules and resources are contained and uploaded to Play, but it can be setup so Play only distributes some of that depending in circumstance.